# "Set-Acl" not working when owner is not administrator

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

Getting the below error when trying to set permissions via PowerShell.

> Set-Acl : The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.

I am trying to assign modify permission to folders and files within a folder recursively using PowerShell. The script works fine on folders where administrator is owner, but throws an error when the administrator is not owner:

```
$location = "E:\Data\Path_of_folder"
$group = "SecurityGroup_RW"
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($group, "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$folders = Get-Childitem $location -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSISContainer}
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $path = $folder.FullName
    $acl = (Get-Item $path).GetAccessControl('Access')
    $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl $path $acl
}
```

I should be able to set the permissions for all folders, not just the folders for which `Administrator` is the owner.

Comment: Remove the `'Access'` argument from `GetAccessControl()`

Comment: Hi Mathias,Still the same issue :-(

Comment: Use `icacls`. `Set-Acl` tends to get its panties in a bunch when the user trying to change the permissions isn't the owner (or member of the owner group).

Comment: icacls also did not work. It did not generate any error, but did not add permissions to the folder to which administrator is not owner.

$folder = "E:\Data\Path_of_folder"
icacls.exe $folder /grant "SecurityGroup_RW:(OI)(CI)(M)"